Improving accuracy of cv.findCirclesGrid
I am trying to calibrate a camera using openCV's cv.calibrateCamera. The problem that I am encountering is the accuracy of points found with cv.findCirclesGrid. They seem to be off by a bit, with respect to the original images. One example looks like this. Here the blue circles represent the detected centres.
My question is, how should one try to improve centre position?
I was thinking of iterating over all detected points and then refine its position with algorithms like Hough circle transform or using cv.connectedComponentsWithStats(). Or maybe to fit an ellipse and find its geometric centre?
What would be the right approach?
My code looks like this:
grid_w = 13
grid_h = 15

# prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
objp = np.zeros((grid_w*grid_h,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:grid_w,0:grid_h].T.reshape(-1,2)

# Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space
imgpoints = [] # 2d points in image plane.


fx, fy = 16 / 3.45 * 10**3, 16 / 3.45 * 10**3
cx, cy = 2464/2, 2056/2


mtx = np.array([[fx, 0,  cx],
                [0,  fy, cy], 
                [0,  0,  1]])

images = glob.glob(path + '/*.bmp')

for fname in images:
    img = cv.imread(fname, cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

    # Find the cirlces 
    ret, corners = cv.findCirclesGrid(img, (grid_w,grid_h), None, flags = cv.CALIB_CB_SYMMETRIC_GRID)
    
    # If found, add object points and image points 
    if ret == True:
        objpoints.append(objp)
        imgpoints.append(corners)



ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, img.shape[::-1], mtx, None, flags=cv.CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS)


context, specifically the comments: https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/79140106

@ChristophRackwitz your link is not working

My problem was solved in so called 'staging ground', but I don't think the conversation there can be made public. All in all, it turned out to be only a matter of poor plotting (matplotlib) and the accuracy was actually fine.
